# How to load serverside function by ajax-request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I asked myself if it would possible to load an associated PHP-function within one PHP-file by an Ajax-Request. For sure it should possible, but how?

Normaly, in my webapplication every Ajax-function (on the clientside) calls a specific PHP-file by its URL. For example this Ajax calls includes/ajax.php.

```
function ajaxRequest( ) {

    $( ".loading-overlay" ).show();
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url : "includes/ajax.php",
        type : "POST",
        data : $("#nodes").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        cache : false,
        success: function( data ) {
            drawChart( data.chart_data );
            currentGauge( data.current_data.current );
            tableMaxMin( data.maxmin_data );
            tableAvgDays( data.avg_data );
            $('#loading').hide();
            $( ".loading-overlay" ).hide();
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nERROR: "+ err);
        }
    });
}
```

The most of my applications has more then one Ajax-request. I considered it is not very efficienty and especially confusing to create for each ajax-function a new PHP-file. A much better solution would be storing every different (serverside) response-engine in just one PHP-file with different function.

Only for understanding, I'm searching for something like this:

```
function ajaxRequest( ) {

    $( ".loading-overlay" ).show();
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url : "includes/ajax.php",
        function: parseData(),  //<--- This is not allowed
        type : "POST",
        data : $("#nodes").serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        cache : false,
        success: function( data ) {
            drawChart( data.chart_data );
            currentGauge( data.current_data.current );
            tableMaxMin( data.maxmin_data );
            tableAvgDays( data.avg_data );
            $('#loading').hide();
            $( ".loading-overlay" ).hide();
        },
        error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nERROR: "+ err);
        }
    });
}
```

So, how to load a the specific response-engine by function not by url?

Comment: Include an "action" field in the form, on which the server-side script can branch. Of course, it doesn't have to be "action" but this is a natural choice for English speakers.

Comment: you can not load server file in just one request to client side because most of the data are dependent on user or something else then how will u load the data to client side, instead of creating multiple ajax file for different request u can use one PHP file for all the request that is possible by passing action=requestname and use case in your ajax file to identify the request.

Comment: So it is needed to query the different forms at serverside in ajax.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ajax call from one file

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/ajax.php?action=login",
    method: "POST",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
})
```

ajax call from another file

```
$.ajax({
    url: "includes/ajax.php?action=userdetail",
    method: "POST",
    data : {'userId': 1},
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

//ajax.php

```
<?php

    $action = $_GET['action'];
    extract($_POST);
    switch($action){
        case 'login' :
            //code for login
        break;
        case 'userdetail' :
            //code for userdetail you can use directly $userId to access post variable as we have use `extract` method.
        break;
        default :
             echo json_encode(array("message"=>"Please provide proper action"));
        break;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ah fine, this was easy! Thank you.